# C# - Doesn't allow me to return "this" as a type when interface for type is implemented

Tags: c#

I have this:

```
public class MyClass<T>:  IView
{
        public View View()
        {
            return this;
        }
        public void Render(ViewContext viewContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer)
        {
            // We should cycle though all supported controls and generate HTML for them.
            // What about the validation binding?

            typeof(T).GetFields().ToList<FieldInfo>().ForEach(x => writer.WriteLine(x.FieldType + " is called " + x.Name + "</br>"));           
        }  


}
```

I get an error that it cannot implicitly cast this to a View. When I attempt a cast it fails. Is there any way to do this? Why does it fail?

**EDIT: View implementation added. I trimmed too much out of the class. I apologize for not posting enough.**

Comment: I don't know too much C#, but  this is a type of MyClass<T>? I don't see how MyClass<T> can be converted to view?

Comment: what is that it dosen't sem like a constructor..then why your method name is same as Return Type.. is this a typo.. As for answer may be bothe the T and View may not be compatible with each other.. but you havent even used `T` anywhere.. then you should be using specific class instead of generic.. if that is the case

Comment: IView only defines that MyClass must implement View(), Since MyClass does not have View as it's base class it will not be able to be returned as View.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MyClass<T>` instances are not convertible to `View`. They are only convertible to `IView`. If you want to inherit from `View` class, you should just do that. Implementing a similarly named interface doesn't magically cause the class to inherit from the base type you need:

```
public class MyClass<T> : View { ... }
```

Comment: I would add..even if View implements IView

Answer (score 3):

Any of these will work.

```
public class MyClass<T>:  IView
{
    public IView View()
    {
        return this;
    }   
}
```

Or

```
public class MyClass<T>:  IView
{
    public MyClass<T> View()
    {
        return this;
    }   
}
```

MyClass is **not** a View and cannot be returned as one as you try to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
public class MyClass<T>:  IView
{
        public View View()
        {
            return (MyClass<T>) this;
        }   
}
```

Comment: Please try indenting your code when you post answers. You can either indent each line with 4 spaces manually, or select the entire block and press the `{}` button on the toolbar.

Comment: -1 because you're showing what seems like a random code experiment without explaining why this should work. Why have you decided to change `MyClass<T>` to `MyClass`? _(**UPDATE:** Never mind that question. Your answer was updated in the meantime.)_ Why have you added an explicit cast to `MyClass` when the return type is `View`? etc.

Comment: @stakx: Just for clarification, I didn't actually *update* the answer, at least not in the sense that I *changed* any of the code. `MyClass<T>` was there originally, it just didn't show up because the block wasn't formatted code.